# check to see if a list of times fall within a range of time pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1

```
        name    start               end
30745   c   25/02/2020 09:23:53 25/02/2020 09:24:00
30746   c   25/02/2020 09:24:04 25/02/2020 09:24:11
30747   c   25/02/2020 09:24:19 25/02/2020 09:24:26
30748   a   25/02/2020 09:24:37 25/02/2020 09:24:40
30749   b   25/02/2020 09:24:38 25/02/2020 09:24:45
30750   c   25/02/2020 09:24:50 25/02/2020 09:24:58
```

df2

```
   start                 name
2020-02-25 09:24:38     a
2020-02-25 09:24:38     a
2020-02-25 09:24:38     b
2020-02-25 09:24:41     b
2020-02-25 09:24:41     e
2020-02-25 09:24:41     b
```

I want to check if time from df2 falls into the range in df1 and if it does check if name matches.
If name matches, create another column in df2 giving it a label of yes. And if name does not match, labelling it no.

Ideally df2 should look like:

```
   start                 name    label
2020-02-25 09:24:38     a        yes
2020-02-25 09:24:38     a        yes
2020-02-25 09:24:38     b        no
2020-02-25 09:24:41     b        yes
2020-02-25 09:24:41     e        no
2020-02-25 09:24:41     b        yes
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do your `name` in the expected output differ from `name` in the input?

Comment: Sorry, changed!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframes contain equal indexes, I'd first check if name matches, then check if dates are satisfied:

```
# check if names match
df2['name_match'] = (df1['name'] == df2['name'])

# check if dates match
df2['dt_match'] = (df1['start'] <= df2['start']) & (df1['end'] <= df2['start'])

# finally, map to a label (using boolean logic)
df2['label'] = (df2['name_match'] * df2['dt_match']).map({True:"yes", False:"no"})

# You can then remove the columns you created
df2.drop(columns=['name_match', 'dt_match'], inplace=True)
```

If your df is massive, you can speed this all up by applying boolean logic to the datetime comparison, only checking rows which satisfy `name_match`.

**Note:** It appears your indexes do not match, in which case you would need to merge the dataframes or map them using some prioritization heuristic or algorithm.